# ng-flow define maximum number of files

Tags: ng-flow

I am using ng-flow in my app, is there any way to limit the number of files for upload?

A code sample:

```
<div class="thumbnail" ng-show="$flow.files.length">
  <img flow-img="$flow.files[0]" />
</div>
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn" ng-hide="$flow.files.length" flow-btn flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Select image</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn" ng-show="$flow.files.length" flow-btn flow-attrs="{accept:'image/*'}">Change</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" ng-show="$flow.files.length"
     ng-click="$flow.cancel()">
    Remove
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute flow-file-added is expecting a boolean value. 
You can put all your conditions in there. 
$flow.files.length returns the number a files you have already added

For example:

```
<div flow-init flow-files-submitted="$flow.upload()" flow-file-added="$flow.files.length<3"></div>
```

Comment: Good answers *explain* as well as provide code. Consider updating your answer to include an explanation about how this code works and why it is the best option.

Comment: flow-file-added is expecting a boolean value. You can put all your conditions in there. $flow.files.length returns the number a files you have already added.

Comment: Don't just comment. Edit your answer!

Comment: Is there a way to do this for Drag&Drop as well? flow-file-added doesn't work in this case